# Where I can find akka actor model in default scala-lib?

Tags: scala, akka, actor

> Starting with Scala 2.11.0, the Scala Actors library is deprecated.
>   Already in Scala 2.10.0 the default actor library is Akka.

Is there in standard scala library Akka? Or it's needed to get it by myself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not included into scala standart library, you should provide a dependency by yourself. If you are using sbt then add thee following to your build:

```
libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-actor" % "2.2.1"
```

Comment: Thanks! I am little disappointed, because I always think that it's out of the box.

Comment: akka-actor is included in the Scala Distribution, but it is not a part of the Scala Standard Library.

Comment: @brainless actually scala moves to a high modularization of it's features, for example, in next version (2.11) xml will be moved out of std. That is quite reasonable approach -- not everybody needs actors or xml in their applications and keeping std as lightweight as it possible is especially important for Android applications.

Comment: Yep, it make sense. It's no problem to add dependency when you are using sbt or mvn. But I'he faced with problem in my "akka-hello-world" when trying to simple add .jar and all have to work)
Generally it's much harder to reduce standard library to minimal set of needed libs than include all "delicious" libs.